# JQuery autocomplete is 1 character late

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I'm trying to make an autocomplete on an input, but it seems that the results of the autocomplete are 1 character late. So if I type i.e. "Ubuntu" it shows only suggestions for "Ubunt" and then if I press on backspace it completes with "Ubuntu". Here's my code:

```
 $('.searchbar').keyup(function(e){
    url = 'inc/autocomplete.php?q=' + $('.searchbar').val();

    $('.searchbar').autocomplete({
        source: url,
        delay: 0,
    }); 
 });
```

`.searchbar` is an input of type text.

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Try adding a 100ms delay - I think your requests might be queueing.

Comment: JSFiddle not possible because of remote autocomplete (as you can see from the code posted above). @adam I tried with 100ms delay and there is no difference.

Comment: Why are you calling `autocomplete` on it on every keyup? Just to send the query parameter? jQuery UI autocomplete supports that out of the box.

Comment: I kinda learn by trial and error, and autocomplete didn't work after I put it out of the $('.searchbar').keyup block

Comment: If you are using jquery ui's autocomplete you are doing it wrong. [Read the docs](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote)!

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use the [souce](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) function instead of url.

See JQuery UI's [Remote Auto Completion](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) example for more information.

```
$('.searchbar').autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'inc/autocomplete.php',
      dataType: "jsonp",
      data: {
        q: $('.searchbar').val()
      }
...
```